# c# Get All Process Exception

Tags: c#

I have a method that adds each process in a Gridview as a row (Name, PID, Title, Path ...)

I have 64-bit Windows, but Visual Studio is running as 32-bit.

I've changed my project from 'Any CPU' to '64 Bit' and I've tried all the platforms, but I only get one process: `vshost` or when I launch the application with admin privileges I get two :

```
sqlwriter
winlogon
```

I'm so confused. What should I do to fix the problem?

Thanks for your time!

Code:

```
  Process[] Proc = Process.GetProcesses();
  foreach(Process Pr in Proc)
  {
      string Name = Pr.ProcessName;
      string PID = Pr.Id.ToString();
      string Title = Pr.MainWindowTitle;
      string Priority = "N/A";
      string Path = "N/A";

      try
      {
          Priority =  Pr.PriorityClass.ToString();
          Path = Pr.Modules[0].FileName;
      }
      catch(Exception) {
      }
```

Comment: Show us your code, how do you read all processes ?

Comment: i was getting an exception on Priority =  Pr.PriorityClass.ToString(); cause of priviliges but i fixed it , NOW i get only 2 result on 86 bits and No result on other CPUS

Comment: Here you go ! , thanks for your time  !